# Scrapy: How can i change a new proxy with middleware when i get 403/302?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

i have write down the middleware:

```
def process_request(self, request, spider):
    request = self.change_proxy(request)   # set request proxy

def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
    if response.status != 200:
        self.delete_proxy()           # remove unusable proxy
        return request.copy()         # send request to process_request to change proxy
    return response

def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
    self.delete_proxy()              # remove unusable proxy
    # if comment the code below, i will not get 302. but maybe i will lost crawl some webpage?
    return request.copy()            # send request to process_request to change proxy
```

First, I have some proxies in redis, what i want to do is:

1. give each request a random proxy,
2. when the connection to proxy failed(process_exception called), change a new proxy and re-crawl the webpage.
3. when proxy is banned by the website(response.status != 200), change a new proxy and re-crawl the webpage.

BUT when I run my spider for a few minutes, I always get 302 or `process_exception` always be called, why? If I restart my spider, it works ok only in the first few minutes... (so the proxy ip is ok, whats wrong with my code?)
How can I do this the right way?

Comment: Please, show the content of the exceptions you get.

Comment: Also, you will have to use `request.replace(dont_filter=True)` to bypass the duplicates filter